# Example off addPreferenceFromIntent in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is there any example on `addPreferenceFromIntent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I can give you a quick example,

**Step 1**

Create a `PreferenceFragment` and provide it with an Intent that identifies an `Activity`.

The Activity will have some meta-data associated with it that the `PreferenceFragment` will use to create its layout.

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivityWithPreferences.class);
        addPreferencesFromIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**

Now you need to create an activity `MyActivityWithPreferences` and add it to the manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MyActivityWithPreferences">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.preference"
                android:resource="@xml/preference_from_intent" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please notice the meta-data element as the child of the activity there which will use the specified resource for creating its layout.

**Step 3**

Here is an example of such a resource file which you can use to inflate the layout of your preference screen.

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="screen_preference"
                  android:title="Title Screen Preferences"
                  android:summary="Summary Screen Preferences">

  <CheckBoxPreference android:key="next_screen_checkbox_preference"
                      android:title="Next Screen Toggle Preference Title"
                      android:summary="Next Screen Toggle Preference Summary" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If the answer has helped you a bit, please upvote it. I wrote such an in-depth answer just to help you in it.

Comment: @AritraRoy current material theme didn't apply on resources loaded from inent. How can I apply my current context (application) theme on these preferences? Both activities have defined themes.